# how to use a returned promise to run a console message

Tags: javascript

I just made a scenario like this:

```
function first()
{
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
  {
    setTimeout((function()
    {
        console.log("first");
    }), 2000);

   });
}

function main()
{
  first();
  console.log("second")
}

main();
```

The output is second then first. How can I use the promise to print the second console message after the first one ? I know similar question are being asked but there were about function and storing promises into variables. I couldn't understand how to use it in my case.

Many thanks

Comment: a promise has a `.then` method - here is a [basic guide on using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `.then` on a `Promise` in order to run a function when that Promise resolves. You also need to call `resolve()` in the `setTimeout` to indicate that you want the `Promise` to resolve when the timeout callback runs:

```js
function first() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("first");
      resolve();
    }, 2000);

  });
}

function main() {
  first()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("second")
    });
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `async/await` (note the changes to the `main()` method):

```
function first()
{
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
  {
    setTimeout((function()
    {
        console.log("first");
        resolve();
    }), 2000);

   });
}

async function main()
{
  await first();
  console.log("second")
}

main();
```